# Automate a LEN() function in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, character

Good day,

I am trying to replicate the *LEN()* function from Excel in Word and make it as much automated as the programs allows it to be.

I've managed to create a short Module, that counts the number of characters of a certain sell and then posts the results to the cell on the right:

```
Sub NumChars()
With Selection.Paragraphs(1)
    .Next.Range.Text = .Range.Characters.Count
End With
End Sub
```

This is the result:

[image]

Now, the inconvenience is that if I would have multiple rows, then I have to do this for each and everyone of them, therefore the question is, **how can the VBA be modified, so that it repeats the function until in reaches the last row?** So for example I once press the "Run" button being in the first row and it (re)calculates all the number of characters for each cell in that column until it reaches the last row.

Every help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't post it to the right, it posts it instead of the next paragraph's text. It only happens so that the next paragraph is the next cell. If this is indeed for tables, you should operate on `Cells` instead. If this is indeed for free text, you should specify what to do with all the overwriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is right, but you need to combine it with looping through each row of the table, as in this example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim mydoc As Document
    Set mydoc = ThisDocument
    
    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In mydoc.Tables
        CountMyChars tbl
    Next tbl
End Sub

Sub CountMyChars(ByRef tbl As Table)
    Const CHAR_COL As Long = 2
    Const COUNT_COL As Long = 3
    
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    For row = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        '--- assumes the characters to count are in Column 2
        '    and the cell to hold the count is Column 3
        tbl.Cell(row, COUNT_COL).Range.Text = tbl.Cell(row, CHAR_COL).Range.Characters.Count
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You might do better with code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Long
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub
  With .Tables(1)
    For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
      .Cell(r, 3).Range.Text = Len(.Cell(r, 2).Range.Text) - 2
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code only runs on the selected table, rather than all tables in the document (which could compromise those other tables), and excludes the end-of-cell marker (which counts as 2 characters) from the character count. As coded, the process starts at the top row; if that row contains headings, change 'r = 1' to 'r = 2'.